# C# file output (.exe) can run code even without the program running

Tags: c#, embed, exe

Okay, I admit the title is somewhat vague and I don't know how to describe it in title. Even the tags I'm not sure what to put for this question.

So, I have an encryption & decryption program (in c#), I can encrypt it to become .exe file. Now, I want to decrypt it back without running the program. I just wanted to run the .exe file and it will decrypt itself (using my own algorithm I had already).

What I have in concept right now is that I need to embed my decryption code when it was encrypted. Is there any way around it? Google() can't really helped me since I don't know the terms about this. Maybe anyone here can help me?

General Idea:

my encryption function:

```
Encrypt(string input, string output, string key)
{
    .....after all encryption happens....
    <produce output which is .exe>
    <embed the decryption function, which will run when .exe is launched>
}
```

my decryption function (the one need to be embeded while encrypting files):

```
Decrypt(string input, string output, string key)
```

If I make myself confusing, please just remind me about it. I will try to make it more comprehensible. Thank you very much.

Comment: `I can encrypt it to become .exe file` - this one scares the hell out of me...

Comment: Do you mean you use a bootstrapper to decrypt an exe that you store internally for running and now you want to destroy it when you're done running?

Comment: Are you encrypting a string and putting it into a file with a .exe extension?

Comment: I think he has a bootstrapper to run the exe, but now he wants to run the decryption part and store the exe (unencrypted) to a file, without running it.

Comment: @Catha: no i'm not encrypting a string, I'm encrypting a file, I'm using the filename as the string to find the path where the file is.

Comment: @Jim & theGreat: No, i'm not using bootstraper, I'm just writing a new file with that function having the extension of .exe

Comment: @Ilya: Is it illegal? What I meant encrypt is to make the file unreadable by playing with the bits only. The method of decryption is pretty much the same, only going backwards. There is a password key included to determine how the bits will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestion:

**Complex Solution:**

1. Encrypt your file ane make en.exe
2. Open en.exe and embed it byte by byte to a string in a project which run Decryptor as main function.
3. Compile project of step 2 . The result is self decryotor of itself

Note: You can do step 2 on fly. I means your encryptor make this C# project at run time and then compile it. This method use RunTime Compile concept.

**Easy Solution:**

Use `WinRar`. It can encrypt/decrypt, password protection and make EXE file. All are very easy and can be done with command line.

Comment: no point of me learning if use winrar, but I really like the complex solution, I'm going to give it a try, thanks a lot :)

Comment: I think I see what you want to do...you want to turn a file into a program that will turn back into itself when you run it like an executeable...sort of like the self extracting archives that a lot of the Zip programs can create.....yea, the complex solution is the way to go, but I would look into the simple solution if I were you, why re-invent the wheel...there is already code out there that does what you want....

Comment: @user2002495 You can complex solution with better performance and extendability. But you need to know PE file format( PE=Portable Executable= Windows .exe , .dll , ... files format) and make it EXE file yourself (Compiler do this and make life easy:D)

Comment: @Nevyn : Zip programs will not let you to determine encryption algorithm. They use limited methods. Also sometimes you must re-invent the wheel, because your are interest in knowledge of it!